# Watching video with mplayer without extra terminal window?

Tags: mplayer

I'm trying to watch a video in mplayer, however when I run the command:

```
mplayer video.flv
```

the terminal window remains open and another window for the video opens.

Is there a way I can run the video from the terminal but watch without the terminal window remaining open?

I've tried:

```
mplayer video.flv < /dev/null &
```

as suggested in their FAQ, however I get the process ID then a second or so later the output returns to the terminal before the video window opens. If I do then close the terminal window when the video window is open, the video window closes as well.

MPlayer version:

```
MPlayer svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.7 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
```

Using gnome-terminal with i3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start it like this:

```
(nohup mplayer video.flv >/dev/null &) && exit
```

If mplayer starts successfully, the shell will exit and the terminal window close (unless you're running one shell in another, or something like that); if mplayer fails, the shell will remain open and you'll see the stderr output in it, so you can figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Brilliant- that does exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! (And I'd be obliged if you'd click the green checkmark under the vote buttons on my answer... :)

Comment: Done! I was unable to because I needed to wait ten minutes before choosing an answer, then I got a bit distracted.